# "drush make" is unable to determine the MIME type

Tags: drush

On every .js library that needs to be downloaded, I keep getting errors like the following one.

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js.
> Unable to determine mime type for jquery-ui.min.js`

I've read posts like [Make fails to identify mime type of json2.js (identified as .tar)](https://drupal.org/node/1825946) that describes a similar issue, but I can't figure out where to install the patch file since I'm getting errors and nothing ends up being installed or moving past the download fase.

I've found that with more simple make files, if I just get rid of the libraries that are requiring the .js file, I can get through everything without errors, and it will actually install. However, I really need to solve this problem because I need these libraries.

I'm currently using Drush 6.0 and I've installed all of the stuff that was reported in [how to prepare mediafront_demo installation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1260084), but I had to comment out media_module and file_entity stuff.

I'm using Windows 8 and the mysysgit (mingw32) for my prompt.

I created a smaller test.make file to try and debug this. It has only the latest Drupal 7 core and libraries for html5bp, jquery, and jqueryui.  html5bp seems to be downloading fine.

These are the libraries handled by the .make file.

```php
libraries[html5bp][download][type] = "file"
libraries[html5bp][download][url] = "http://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/zipball/v3.0.2stripped"
libraries[jquery][download][type] = "file"
libraries[jquery][download][url] = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"
libraries[jqueryui][download][type] = "file"
libraries[jqueryui][download][url] = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"
```

I ran it with `--debug` and this is what I get. (I've omitted the first half to keep it short because everything with the core is working fine already.)

```
Returned from hook drush_pm_download                 
Command dispatch complete              
Peak memory usage was 9.21 MB            
drupal-7.x-dev downloaded.                     
Undefined property: DrushMakeProject_Library::$type make.project.inc:147 Executing: wget --version  
Calling is_writable(C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Loca/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d)  
Calling rename(C:\Users\jsmith85\AppData\Local\Temp\dowFB52.tmp, C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72dv3.0.2stripped)
html5bp downloaded from http://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/zipball/v3.0.2stripped.
Examining C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/v3.0.2stripped headers.  
Mime type for C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/v3.0.2stripped is application/zip 
Examining C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/v3.0.2stripped headers.  
Mime type for C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/v3.0.2stripped is application/zip  
Calling chdir(C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d)  
Executing: unzip C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/v3.0.2stripped -d C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509  
Archive:  C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/v3.0.2stripped5f341a34e8a37b8deeb1f416fa2a7b8a0a78638a  
  creating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/
  extracting: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/.gitattributes
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/.gitignore
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0
559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/.htaccess
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/404.html
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/apple-touch-icon.png
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/crossdomain.xml
  creating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/css/
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/css/style.css
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/favicon.ico
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/humans.txt
  creating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/img/
  extracting: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/img/.gitignore
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/index.html
  creating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/js/
  creating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/js/libs/
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.js
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/js/plugins.js
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/js/script.js
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/readme.md
  inflating: C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f/robots.txt
Calling chdir(C:\wamp\www\fit3)  
Calling drush_delete_dir(C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/__build__/sites/all/libraries/html5bp, 1)  
Calling is_readable(C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f)
Calling is_writable(C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/__build__/sites/all/libraries)
Calling  rename(C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/drush_tmp_1400527621_537a5b0559509/h5bp-html5-boilerplate-359a13f,
C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/__build__/sites/all/libraries/html5bp)  
Undefined property: DrushMakeProject_Library::$type                       make.project.inc:147 [59.42 sec, 7.53 MB]
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O "C:\\Users\\jsmith85\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\dow300.tmp" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
  SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
  syswgetrc = c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
Calling is_readable(C:\Users\jsmith85\AppData\Local\Temp\dow300.tmp)  
Calling is_writable(C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d)  
Calling rename(C:\Users\jsmith85\AppData\Local\Temp\dow300.tmp,          
C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/jquery.min.js)  
jquery downloaded from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js.  
Examining C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/jquery.min.js headers.  
Unable to determine mime type from header bytes 0x2a2f of C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/jquery.min.js.  
Examining C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/jquery.min.js extension.  
Unable to determine mime type for jquery.min.js.  
Calling is_readable(C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/jquery.min.js)  
Calling is_writable(C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/__build__/sites/all/libraries/jquery)  
Calling rename(C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/jquery.min.js, C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/__build__
/sites/all/libraries/jquery/jquery.min.js)  
Undefined property: DrushMakeProject_Library::$type                     
make.project.inc:147  
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O "C:\\Users\\jsmith85\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\dow4E5.tmp" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js  
  SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
  syswgetrc = c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
Calling is_readable(C:\Users\jsmith85\AppData\Local\Temp\dow4E5.tmp)     Calling is_writable(C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d)  
Calling rename(C:\Users\jsmith85\AppData\Local\Temp\dow4E5.tmp, C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/jquery-ui
.min.js)  
jqueryui downloaded from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js.  
Examining C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/jquery-ui.min.js headers.  
Unable to determine mime type from header bytes 0x2a2f of C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/jquery-ui.min.js.  
Examining C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/jquery-ui.min.js
extension.  
Unable to determine mime type for jquery-ui.min.js. 
Calling is_readable(C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/jquery-ui.min.js)  
Calling is_writable(C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/__build__/sites/all/libraries/jqueryui)  
Calling rename(C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/jquery-ui.min.js, C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/__build__
/sites/all/libraries/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js)  
Returned from hook drush_make  
Command dispatch complete
Peak memory usage was 9.38 MB
```

Comment: If you are using recent drush, there will be no place to apply patches from linked report, as it was fixed on November 3, 2012 and since then code in the patched part is already patched (or was totally rebuilt, rendering patches not applicable). Response headers from ajax.googleapis.com do contain `Content-Type text/javascript; charset=UTF-8`, so it is not a server issue. Test yourself, maybe your proxy strips this header?

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was driving myself crazy trying to figure out how to add mime_magic to my wamp installation.

How do I go about testing my proxy for this? I posted a --debug above and it looks like html5bp is coming through ok (although it throws a notice).

Comment: github uses manyadresses and i sometimes have issues because of the redirects ... when i try it with wget, it goes to `https://codeload.github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/legacy.zip/v3.0.2stripped` , try putting that in your make file ?

Comment: so just to make sure, what do you get for 'drush version` ?

Comment: Drush Version : 6.0 

The boilerplate is already going through ok. However, the actual js files are not. I'm thinking it's got to do with the js file-types, like @Molot was mentioning earlier, because those always comeback with errors and, in some cases (like with how views_slideshow calls another make file to download carousel.js) I can't just control it with just my make file. 

It could very well be the proxy, I just have no idea how to test/fix it beyond drush --debug. I'm working on a college network btw, however I've not had any problems with drush, git or pulling down data before.

Comment: Tried doing this on a different computer, on a different network, and using XAMPP instead of WAMP and I got the exact same error. It has to be something with drush, windows 8, or an uninstalled dependency.  Any ideas? Other people have to be running into this.

Answer (score 1):

In a successful run of `drush make`, the message may be:

> Mime type for /tmp/make_tmp_1403284094_53a46a7e2ceaf/jquery.min.js is text/html

In the log you posted, `drush make` tries to examine the file headers to determine the file MIME type.

> Examining C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/jquery-ui.min.js headers.
> Unable to determine mime type from header bytes 0x2a2f of C:/Users/jsmith85/AppData/Local/Temp/make_tmp_1400527562_537a5acaaa72d/jquery-ui.min.js.

This happens when PHP has no *fileinfo* extension and Drush tries to guess  the MIME type with [`drush_mime_content_type()`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/6.x/includes/drush.inc#L840).

You can verify if the required extension is installed with `php -i | grep fileinfo`. If it's installed the output will be the following one.

> fileinfo
> fileinfo support => enabled

As for installation instructions, from  the [PHP's fileinfo installation page](http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php), Windows users must include the bundled php_fileinfo.dll file in
php.ini to enable the extension.